# error=$(mkdir test 2>&1) What is the meaning of that expression?

Tags: bash, shell, io-redirection, command-substitution

I have the following shell script:

```
error=$(mkdir test 2>&1)
```

I know that the variable 'error' will get the error result of the mkdir command if there is an error, but I can't understand how 2>&1 works, could someone explain it? Thanks!

Comment: TL:DR summary of the answers: it captures stderr and stdout, by redirecting stderr to wherever stdout is going.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The syntax

```
x="$(some_command)"
```

will run `some_command` and the *output* of that is returned and stored in the variable `"$x"`.

Now, normally, programs send "normal output" to the "standard out" stream (`stdout`, file handle #1) and error messages to the "standard error" stream (`stderr`, file handle #2).

The redirection semantic `2>&1` means (roughly speaking; it's a little more complicated under the covers) "send `stderr` to `stdout`".  So error messages and output messages are mixed together.

So we can combine the two:

```
x="$(some_command 2>&1)"
```

will return the output *and* the error messages and put them into `$x`.

In your case

```
error="$(mkdir test 2>&1)"
```

means that `$error` will contain the output (which is empty) and the error (which *may* contain a string if an error occurs).  The result is that   `$error` will contain any error message from the `mkdir` command.

We can see this in action.

```
$ error="$(mkdir /)"
mkdir: cannot create directory '/': File exists
$ echo "$error"

$ error="$(mkdir / 2>&1)"
$ echo "$error"
mkdir: cannot create directory '/': File exists
```

In the first case the error message is printed immediately because it's sent to `stderr`, and the variable is empty.  In the second case we redirect stderr to stdout and so it is captured and stored in the `$error` variable.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot! It is very didactic your explanation!

Answer (score 2):

It means, poetically speaking: send the error stream to the same "channel" as the normal output. `2` stands for error(s). `1` is the main-line, or the *standard output*. `&1` indicates the way, where the standard output goes. By default, it goes to the screen, and in this substitution context: `$( )`, it goes to the variable, becomes its value. And `>` is redirection. All together `2>&1` means: redirect errors the way of standard output.

Comment: Thanks, you helped me a lot! I like your poetic explanation!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to choose me over Stephen's dry lecture next time !

Answer (score 1):

It captures stderr and stdout, by redirecting stderr to stdout (taking effect after the `$()` command substitution has connected stdout to a pipe to the parent shell).

The `&` in `>&1` makes the difference between referencing another file descriptor instead opening a file called `1`.

The `2>` means to redirect stderr, as usual.